# display name,emp max salary from customers and also displaying orders of that employee using joins

Tags: sql

Sample table customers .where ‘Id’ has primary key constraint.

Sample customers table

```
Id  Sal     Name    address
1   40000   Name1   Hyd
2   30000   Name2   Bangalore
3   20000   Name3   Mumbai
4   50000   Name4   Delhi
5   25000   Name5   chennai
```

Sample orders table

```
client_id   Product Quantity
2           Jeans   1
3           Shoes   2
4           Watch   1
5           Shirt   3
```

Now I want to select ‘customer name’ who has ‘MAX’ salary and what product he has ordered i.e product details ‘product’ and ‘quantity’ using joins.

My table should look like

```
Name    Sal     Product quantity
Name4   50000   watch     1
```

i have 'id' has primary key in customers table and 'clent_id' as foreign key in products table.

Comment: Does your orders table have a link to the customers table?

Comment: i have 'id' has primary key in customers table and 'clent_id' as foreign key in products table.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will get the customer with the greatest salary `MAX(Sal)` and `JOIN` any associated rows from the orders table.

```
SELECT
    c.Name,
    c.Sal,
    o.Product,
    o.Quantity
FROM Customers c
    left join Orders o ON o.Client_Id = c.Id
WHERE
    c.Sal = (SELECT MAX(Sal) from Customers)
ORDER BY
    c.Name;
```

Note, if more than one customer has the maximum salary, they will all be listed.

Comment: dude thanks for your suggestion.....but the table is showing null values for 'product' and 'quantity'....i am not getting the exact out put...

Comment: Check the JOIN criteria :  o.Client_Id = c.Id. You may have to change that. Also, if the customer with the highest salary doesn't have any orders, those fields will be null.